# How to program a new keyfob for 2011 Hyundai Accent

Tags: hyundai, keyless-entry, accent, fob

I bought `2011 Hyundai Accent` Manual stick-shift, few days ago. The dealer only had 1 key.
I saw on Amazon Keyless fob for this model of the car.
Can I program it, or do I need a help of professional to do it?
How do I know if the car had one before or if it’s capable of being programmable, for the lack of better word!?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! From what I'm seeing, you need a programmer to pair it with your car. You can do it yourself, but you'll have to look for what's available. I saw a video which showed that Dorman sells the programmer with their fobs. To figure out if the car had them in the first place, take your VIN to a Hyundai parts counter and ask them for the specs on the car. They can pull it up in their computer and tell you if it came with a fob in the first place.